# About how to add a new column to an existing DataFrame with random values in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, random, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

i have a dataframe with a parquet file and I have to add a new column with some random data, but I need that random data different each other. This is my actual code and the current version of spark is 1.5.1-cdh-5.5.2:

```
val mydf = sqlContext.read.parquet("some.parquet")
// mydf.count()
// 63385686 
mydf.cache

val r = scala.util.Random
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
def myNextPositiveNumber :String = { (r.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE) + 1 ).toString.concat("D")}
val myFunction = udf(myNextPositiveNumber _)
val myNewDF = mydf.withColumn("myNewColumn",lit(myNextPositiveNumber))
```

with this code, I have this data:

```
scala> myNewDF.select("myNewColumn").show(10,false)
+-----------+
|myNewColumn|
+-----------+
|889488717D |
|889488717D |
|889488717D |
|889488717D |
|889488717D |
|889488717D |
|889488717D |
|889488717D |
|889488717D |
|889488717D |
+-----------+
```

It looks like that the udf myNextPositiveNumber is invoked only once, isn't?

update
confirmed, there is only one distinct value:

```
scala> myNewDF.select("myNewColumn").distinct.show(50,false)
17/02/21 13:23:11 WARN ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl
17/02/21 13:23:11 WARN ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl
17/02/21 13:23:11 WARN ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl
17/02/21 13:23:11 WARN ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl
17/02/21 13:23:11 WARN ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl
17/02/21 13:23:11 WARN ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl
17/02/21 13:23:11 WARN ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl
...

+-----------+                                                                   
|myNewColumn|
+-----------+
|889488717D |
+-----------+
```

what do I am doing wrong?

Update 2: finally, with the help of @user6910411 I have this code:

```
val mydf = sqlContext.read.parquet("some.parquet")
// mydf.count()
// 63385686 
mydf.cache

val r = scala.util.Random

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val accum = sc.accumulator(1)

def myNextPositiveNumber():String = {
   accum+=1
   accum.value.toString.concat("D")
}

val myFunction = udf(myNextPositiveNumber _)

val myNewDF = mydf.withColumn("myNewColumn",lit(myNextPositiveNumber))

myNewDF.select("myNewColumn").count

// 63385686
```

update 3

Actual code generates data like this:

```
scala> mydf.select("myNewColumn").show(5,false)
17/02/22 11:01:57 WARN ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl
+-----------+
|myNewColumn|
+-----------+
|2D         |
|2D         |
|2D         |
|2D         |
|2D         |
+-----------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

It looks like the udf function is invoked only once, isn't? I need a new random element in that column.

update 4 @user6910411

i have this actual code that increases the id but it is not concatenating the final char, it is weird. This is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf


val mydf = sqlContext.read.parquet("some.parquet")

mydf.cache

def myNextPositiveNumber():String = monotonically_increasing_id().toString().concat("D")

val myFunction = udf(myNextPositiveNumber _)

val myNewDF = mydf.withColumn("myNewColumn",expr(myNextPositiveNumber))

scala> myNewDF.select("myNewColumn").show(5,false)
17/02/22 12:00:02 WARN Executor: 1 block locks were not released by TID = 1:
[rdd_4_0]
+-----------+
|myNewColumn|
+-----------+
|0          |
|1          |
|2          |
|3          |
|4          |
+-----------+
```

I need something like:

```
+-----------+
|myNewColumn|
+-----------+
|1D         |
|2D         |
|3D         |
|4D         |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.3**

It is possible to disable some optimizations using `asNondeterministic` method:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

val f: UserDefinedFunction = ???
val fNonDeterministic: UserDefinedFunction = f.asNondeterministic
```

Please make sure you understand the guarantees before using this option.

**Spark < 2.3**

Function which is passed to udf should be deterministic (with possible exception of [SPARK-20586](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20586)) and nullary functions calls can be replaced by constants. If you want to generate random numbers use on of the built-in functions:

- [`rand`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@rand(seed:Long):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) - *Generate a random column with independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) samples from U[0.0, 1.0].*
- [`randn`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@randn(seed:Long):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) - *Generate a column with independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.) samples from the standard normal distribution.*

and transform the output to obtain required distribution for example:

```
(rand * Integer.MAX_VALUE).cast("bigint").cast("string")
```

Comment: What do you mean with "Please make sure you understand the guarantees before using this option"?
I am using `.asNondeterministic` in Spark 2.4 and it does **not** work with `java.util.UUID.randomUUID()`. The udf generating the random UUID get re-executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `monotonically_increasing_id` to generate random values.

Then you can define a UDF to append any string to it after casting it to String as `monotonically_increasing_id` returns Long by default.

```
scala> var df = Seq(("Ron"), ("John"), ("Steve"), ("Brawn"), ("Rock"), ("Rick")).toDF("names")
+-----+
|names|
+-----+
|  Ron|
| John|
|Steve|
|Brawn|
| Rock|
| Rick|
+-----+

scala> val appendD = spark.sqlContext.udf.register("appendD", (s: String) => s.concat("D"))

scala> df = df.withColumn("ID",monotonically_increasing_id).selectExpr("names","cast(ID as String) ID").withColumn("ID",appendD($"ID"))
+-----+---+
|names| ID|
+-----+---+
|  Ron| 0D|
| John| 1D|
|Steve| 2D|
|Brawn| 3D|
| Rock| 4D|
| Rick| 5D|
+-----+---+
```

Comment: Just a few notes: You should really remove the first line - _You can make use of `monotonicallyIncreasingId` to generate random values_ .  `monotonically_increasing_id` is nothing, but random. It is strictly deterministic, given the distribution. Also `monotonicallyIncreasingId` has been deprecated in 2.0. You should use `monotonically_increasing_id` instead.