# Creating a column independently with value output from an API

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

I need to create a Spark column in Java with the following requirements:
- Column should be created independently. i.e. should be created without any knowledge on other columns in the dataset
- Should have a custom unique value per row returned from an API, e.g: `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` or `MYCLASS.customMethod()`;

I have tried the following:

1) Using a UDF - it works but this is deterministic ([Spark Dataframe Random UUID changes after every transformation/action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42960920/spark-dataframe-random-uuid-changes-after-every-transformation-action))

2) Used `expr("uuid()")`, but this uses the internal implementation and I want to use my own API here.

Any leads on how to create a column independently with the value of an API is appreciated (in Java). Considering the upstream process is deterministic.
Additionally, I am looking at how the sql uuid() was implemented.

Thoughts for now: can I create a custom Expression in Java and pass to the Column constructor.

Comment: Check `MontotonicallyIncreasingID` or `ZipWithUniqueId`

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/42367629/11900243 ?

Comment: @sMaz MontotonicallyIncreasingID and ZipWithUniqueId provide Ids but I want to provide the Java implementation for the value generation.

Comment: @Aleksei rand returns a unique value, but I want to provide the Java implementation for the value generation.